# SQL Server Agent Job cannot kill a task on a machine

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-agent

I have SSIS package which starts a task and then kills it via cmd. This works when executed directly from Visual Studio. However, task is not killed when SQL Server Agent executes a job with this package. Job has proxy with a user.

I created a separate CmdExec job with this proxy and taskkill command but it throws "Access denied" error. Proxy is the same as the user that started the task on that machine.

How to kill a process on a server machine?

Comment: Why do you want SQL Server to be able to kill such a task? Killing a different user's task requires pretty high premissions, and I doubt that the account SQL Server Agent (or the proxy) it's using has those permissions.

Comment: If the task is hanging, it blocks other process execution. The thing is it's the same user. It works via cmd on that machine and when executed from VS but not from SQL Server Agent even though the job is executed as that user (with a proxy).